# How to change structure of existing columns, based on old values during migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

During development, structure of column has been changed, so it's needed to adopt old users data to new format in production. It looks like issue that can be solved by migration. The problem is, I'm not an experienced ruby specialist, so it would be great to have advice how to implement it.

To make things clear, I'll give an example of what happened in my project.

There is table `users`. This table contains next columns,

- id
- user_type
- description

`description` here is just JSON string that looks like that in old implementation,

- first_name
- last_name
- address

After changes, instead of `first_name` and `last_name` we have `full_name`, only for users with type 'customer'.

So, how can I migrate my old data to new format? Thanks.

Comment: What is datatype of `description` ? provide schema, and which rails version do you use ?

Comment: It is possible that your datatype can be `json` or string with serialized as hash

Comment: @ray It's a json.

Comment: And ruby version is 2.6.0.

Comment: You can directly update value by rake also! Provided answer or You can run code through console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your respective model `User` must have following,

```
serialize :description, Hash
```

Try to write rake in below path,

> lib/tasks/update_users.rake

```
namespace :update_users do

  desc 'Update description for full name for all user'

  task update_description: :environment do
    User.all.each do |user|
      user.description[:full_name] = user.description.delete(:first_name) + ' ' + user.description.delete(:last_name)
      user.save(validate: false)
    end
  end

end
```

And run rake as, `rake update_users:update_description`

Perhaps you can run code through rails console,

```
User.all.each do |user|
  user.description[:full_name] = user.description.delete(:first_name) + ' ' + user.description.delete(:last_name)
  user.save(validate: false)
end
```

Comment: I've done almost this, but in migration instead of task. My problem was simply that - I don't know that I can call model inside migration script. In docs I've read about methods like change_table and thought it's a correct way to make a migration. 

Saw to your answer, I got the idea, and it was not so difficult to select and transform data in needed way.